# unstable wi-fi connection ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, connection, intel-wireless

I've read other questions in askUbuntu, but couldn't solve the problem as I'm new to Linux.

The problem is that the Wifi connection on Ubuntu 14.04 is very unstable. And i don't know what to do.

Below follows the information of my Ubuntu.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, splash, quiet

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 130 [8086:0896] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 130 BGN [8086:5005]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c606]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2232:1020 Silicon Motion 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: samsung-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwldvm                237568  0 
mac80211              720896  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               196608  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              532480  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30064208 (30.0 MB)  TX bytes:14271263 (14.2 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"N.W.A."  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point:    
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:657   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       884     1  0 15:58 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [N.W.A.] ------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           54 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *N.W.A.:         Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 56 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.100
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/N.W.A.]] (600 root)
[connection] id=N.W.A. | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=N.W.A. | mac-address=
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto


##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"N.W.A."
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000009cb758c90
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation 
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     734B867FAAD13922F696215
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        DE:B3:43:0A:26:E6:7D:3D:3B:54:B9:DD:13:25:B3:3A:46:B2:F2:DD
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     E4E96B72E71618C7054030A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        DE:B3:43:0A:26:E6:7D:3D:3B:54:B9:DD:13:25:B3:3A:46:B2:F2:DD
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation 
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode
srcversion:     884420C3D4A6AC329614AEA
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        DE:B3:43:0A:26:E6:7D:3D:3B:54:B9:DD:13:25:B3:3A:46:B2:F2:DD
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     EF182B558008C23DD85EF03
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        DE:B3:43:0A:26:E6:7D:3D:3B:54:B9:DD:13:25:B3:3A:46:B2:F2:DD
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 1
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x0896 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[  612.341055] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[  612.519278] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[  613.358528] wlan0: authenticate with 
[  613.359913] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  613.362406] wlan0: authenticated
[  613.366523] wlan0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[  613.369445] wlan0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  613.372904] wlan0: associated
[  614.216276] wlan0: deauthenticating from  by local choice (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[  614.219187] wlan0: authenticate with 
[  614.219920] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  614.221838] wlan0: authenticated
[  614.223836] wlan0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[  614.226792] wlan0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  614.228701] wlan0: associated
[ 1797.075546] wlan0: deauthenticating from  by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1801.522064] wlan0: authenticate with 
[ 1801.522705] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[ 1801.525243] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1801.528624] wlan0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[ 1801.531527] wlan0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1801.533930] wlan0: associated
[ 2943.940899] wlan0: deauthenticating from  by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2948.828050] wlan0: authenticate with 
[ 2948.828649] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[ 2948.831258] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2948.835080] wlan0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[ 2948.837875] wlan0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 2948.840224] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Any information is very important for me. Thanks